# installing ubuntu on 2 drives

Tags: installation, ssd, drive

if I have a 32 gb ssd and a 1tb hdd can I put /usr and /home on the 1tb and root on the ssd, or is the 32 gb ssd still not big enough for the os? Is there a different or better configuration I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Just select "something other" (or similar) when selecting the partition to install in the ubuntu installer. In the following step you'r able to make partitions and set mount-points for them, also if they are on different drives. 
(To make /home and /usr on the 1tb drive, make two partitions there and give them the mount points /home and /usr, make another on the ssd and give it the mountpoint /).

Although 32gb should be more than enough for ubuntu. I have an 12 GB partition for Ubuntu and only 7 are used.